# Flutter socket io not connecting

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a server using socket.io, and I'm trying to connect to it using https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client. I have ngrok running for the backend. When I run the following code, ngrok shows theres a connection, but  the on connection event in the backend doesn't run, and in flutter it says it's disconnected:

````dart
IO.Socket socket = IO.io('http://my_ngrok_number.ngrok.io', IO.OptionBuilder().setTransports(['websocket']).build());
    print(socket.connected);

    socket.onConnect((_) {
      print('connect');
      socket.emit('msg', 'test');
    });

    socket.onConnecting((data) => print(data));
    socket.onError((data) => print(data));

    // When an event recieved from server, data is added to the stream
    socket.on('event', (data) => streamSocket.addResponse);
    socket.onDisconnect((_) => print('disconnect'));```
Flutter does output 'disconnect' every couple of seconds
````

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue some days ago and the solution is downgrade your socket.io server to version 2.3.0 it will work

Comment: interesting... do u know if they have plans to upgrade it?